# Compare ActiveRecord::Base and ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails

What is difference between ActiveRecord::Base and ActiveRecord?

And why we have to extend ActiveRecord::Base but not ActiveRecord ?

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.authenticate_unsafely(user_name, password)
    where("user_name = '#{user_name}' AND password = '#{password}'").first
  end

  def self.authenticate_safely(user_name, password)
    where("user_name = ? AND password = ?", user_name, password).first
  end

  def self.authenticate_safely_simply(user_name, password)
    where(user_name: user_name, password: password).first
  end
end
```

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html

Comment: `ActiveRecord` is a [module](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record.rb)

and `ActiveRecord::Base` is a [class](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/base.rb)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a great convention, that when you create a gem, you do not create many top level constants. Instead, you should create a single module, which acts like a namespace for your gem. This is exactly what ActiveRecord module is.

ActiveRecord::Base is one of many components of ActiveRecord - others includes classes like `Schema`, `SchemaDumper` `Relation`, `ImmutableRelation` `Validation`, `Scoping` and many many more. You can see the whole list with `ActiveRecord::Base`. If creators of ActiveRecord put all of those constants in the main namespace, you would be largely limited in names you could give to your constants without having conflicts, hence the need of the wrapping module. This module also can contain some extra meta data, so at any point you can check the current version of the gem with `ActiveRecord.version`.